# How to fix background red color TextInputLayout when isEmpty in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

I want **`setError`** when `TextInputLayout` **`isEmpty`**, I write this code but when show error message, set red background for `TextInputLayout`!

I do **not want** set background! **I want** just show the error message.

[image]

**My code:**

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userName)) {
register_UserName_layout.setError("Insert Username");
}
```

**XML code :**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/register_userUsernameTextLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/register_headerLayout"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:textColorHint="#c5c5c5">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/register_userUserNameText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_bg_edit"
        android:hint="نام کاربری"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/bg_input_cursor"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

How can I fix this? Thanks all <3

Comment: The wrapped `EditText`'s background is tinted by the error color when there's an error. Which is not an issue for the default material background. Post your drawable/selector_bg_edit. Follow this Android issue https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=1&start=0&num=100&q=textinputlayout%20background&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&groupby=&sort=&id=186615

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userName)) {
    register_UserName_layout.setError("Insert Username");
    txtInpit.setColorFilter(R.color.white);
}
```

Comment: Can you paste which properties you set in textinput

Comment: Please see this :   `if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userName)) {
register_UserName_layout = (TextInputLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.register_userUsernameTextLayout);
register_UserName_layout.setError("نام کاربری را وارد نکردید");
register_UserName_layout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
}`

Comment: Paste your xml declaration

Comment: Just set color filter your code will working, i check in my app then working, so can you please update this

Comment: I use version 24 of     `compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.0'` but not show me setColorFilter! why ?!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Can you please use 23

Comment: How come is it the right answer? I dont see setColorFilter method.

Answer (score 14):

I have found a workaround to this problem. You just need to create a custom EditText and override the getBackground() method of it to return a new drawable. That way TextInputLayout won't be able to set color filter on the EditText's background, since you do not return EditText's background, but some another drawable. See below:

```
@Override
public Drawable getBackground() {
    return ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.some_drawable);
}
```

and use the custom EditText inside TextInputLayout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <CustomEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_edit_text_bg" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 12):

in my case I added line

<solid android:color="@color/transparent"/>

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <stroke android:color="@color/lightGray" android:width="1dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/transparent"/>
    <padding android:top="7dp" android:bottom="7dp" android:left="7dp" android:right="7dp"/>
    <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
</shape>
```

this results in red border only not entire background

Comment: you saved me hours of investigation :')

Comment: This worked.  I had my background color as white, but changing to transparent fixed the issue

Answer (score 7):

You can subclass TextInputLayout and use that:

```
package com.mypackage;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class CustomTextInputLayout extends TextInputLayout {
    public CustomTextInputLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void drawableStateChanged() {
        super.drawableStateChanged();
        clearEditTextColorfilter();
    }
    @Override
    public void setError(@Nullable CharSequence error) {
        super.setError(error);
        clearEditTextColorfilter();
    }

    private void clearEditTextColorfilter() {
        EditText editText = getEditText();
        if (editText != null) {
            Drawable background = editText.getBackground();
            if (background != null) {
                background.clearColorFilter();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in your layout:

```
<com.mypackage.CustomTextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/register_userUsernameTextLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/register_headerLayout"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:textColorHint="#c5c5c5">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/register_userUserNameText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_bg_edit"
        android:hint="نام کاربری"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/bg_input_cursor"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: I was facing the same problem from yesterday. This helped me to resolve that red background issue. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Bottom line with this issue is check if your EditText has a background color set. If so, remove it and put a background color on your text Input Layout widget instead. This will fix the issue of the big red box. At least it did for me.

Comment: This works and was easy with no other changes. I was using the TextInputEditText to set the background using setBackgroundColor(). Just changed to the TextInputLayout with same method call and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I commented on this as I ran into this again... ! Alright, now I'll learn.

Answer (score 1):

Subclass EditText and apply the follow methods:

Override getBackground and create a Drawable with input background

```
@Override
public Drawable getBackground() {
    return ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.input_background);
}
```

your Drawable input_brackground can be like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid
        android:color="@color/inputBackgroundColor">
    </solid>
</shape>
```

And apply EditText subclassed setBackground after TextInputLayout set error like:

```
private void showTheError(String error){
    textInputLayout.setError(error);
    editTextSubclassed.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.inputBackgroundColor));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Shahin Mursalov's answer, I call method `init()` in the costructor to store the background drawable when the view is created. Also I've overriden method `setBackgroundResource()` to store the background as well, and return it from `getBackground()`:

```
public class CustomEditText extends EditText{

    private Drawable backgroundDrawable;

    public EditTextContext context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public EditTextContext context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        init(attrs);
    }

    public EditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        this.context = context;
        init(attrs);
    }


    public void init(AttributeSet attrs){
        TypedArray attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, new int[]{android.R.attr.background});
        this.backgroundDrawable = attributes.getDrawable(0);
        attributes.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    public void setBackgroundResource(@DrawableRes int resId) {
        this.backgroundDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, resId);
        super.setBackgroundResource(resId);
    }

    @Override
    public Drawable getBackground() {
        if (backgroundDrawable != null){
            return backgroundDrawable;
        } else {
            return super.getBackground();
        }
    }
}
```

This way I can specify a different background in my layout and change it programatically.

Answer (score 0):

first your EditText background selector_bg_edit should be like that

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >


    <item android:drawable="@drawable/code_view_item"
        android:state_focused="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/sign_in_fields"
        android:state_focused="false"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/sign_in_fields"
        android:state_active="false"/>

</selector>
```

And the most important thing is to put  in the drawable to be transparent color like this
code_view_item.xml

```
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#15A859" />
<solid android:color="#00FFFFFF" />
<corners android:radius="12dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is just putting this below lines in my custom edit text class :

```
override fun getBackground(): Drawable {
    return this.context.getDrawable(R.drawable.myDrawableResource)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
yourEdit.background.clearColorFilter()
```